# SSL error when downloading file via https

Tags: ssl, https, common-lisp

I need to download the latest version of quicklisp.lisp from https://beta.quicklisp.org/quicklisp.lisp

At first, I use the common-lisp library usocket and cl+ssl in the code try to download the html page https://www.quicklisp.org/beta/, and it works

```
(usocket:with-client-socket (sock stream "quicklisp.org" 443)
  (let ((https (cl+ssl:make-ssl-client-stream
                stream :unwrap-stream-p t
                :external-format '(:iso-8859-1 :eol-style :lf))))
    (unwind-protect
         (progn
           (format https "GET /beta/ HTTP/1.0~%Host:www.quicklisp.org~%Connection:keep-alive~2%")
           (force-output https)
           (loop for line = (read-line https nil)
              while line do (format t "HTTPS> ~a~%" line)))
      (close https))))
```

Then I modify the codes above slightly for the quicklisp.lisp file:

```
(usocket:with-client-socket (sock stream "beta.quicklisp.org" 443)
  (let ((https (cl+ssl:make-ssl-client-stream
                stream :unwrap-stream-p t
                :external-format '(:iso-8859-1 :eol-style :lf))))
    (unwind-protect
         (progn
           (format https "GET /quicklisp.lisp HTTP/1.1~%Host:beta.quicklisp.org~%Connection:keep-alive~%Accept: */*~2%")
           (force-output https)
           (loop for line = (read-line https nil)
              while line do (format t "HTTPS> ~a~%" line)))
      (close https))))
```

And this time, it fails with no luck.  The error message shows:

```
A failure in the SSL library occurred on handle #.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X7FFFDC019A80) (return code: 1).
SSL error queue:
error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
   [Condition of type CL+SSL::SSL-ERROR-SSL]

Restarts:
 0: [RETRY] Retry SLIME interactive evaluation request.
 1: [*ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.
 2: [ABORT] abort thread (#<THREAD "worker" RUNNING {10088E6223}>)

Backtrace:
  0: (CL+SSL::SSL-SIGNAL-ERROR #.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X7FFFDC019A80) #<FUNCTION CL+SSL::SSL-CONNECT> 1 -1)
      Locals:
        ERROR-CODE = 1
        HANDLE = #.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X7FFFDC019A80)
        ORIGINAL-ERROR = -1
        SYSCALL = #<FUNCTION CL+SSL::SSL-CONNECT>
  1: (CL+SSL:MAKE-SSL-CLIENT-STREAM #<unavailable lambda list>)
      [No Locals]
  2: ((LAMBDA ()))
  3: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (USOCKET:WITH-CLIENT-SOCKET (SOCK STREAM "beta.quicklisp.org" 443) (LET (#) (UNWIND-PROTECT # #))) #<NULL-LEXENV>)
  4: (EVAL (USOCKET:WITH-CLIENT-SOCKET (SOCK STREAM "beta.quicklisp.org" 443) (LET (#) (UNWIND-PROTECT # #))))
  5: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK:INTERACTIVE-EVAL))
```

I know there is another common-lisp library drakma can do what I need here. But I'm just curious why my method fail?

Comment: Can you use `curl` to get the file? Are they using the same ssl version? (which?) From what I could find I'd doubt this is a bug on the lisp side. (Also: Why change from `HTTP/1.0` to `HTTP/1.1`?)

Comment: For the change from HTTP/1.0 to HTTP/1.1, since I failed on HTTP/1.0, just want to switch to HTTP/1.1 make another try

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with how SSL within common lisp works but from the [SSLLabs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=beta.quicklisp.org&s=52.84.213.59&latest) it can be seen that `beta.quicklistp.org` works only when the client uses [Server Name Indication (SNI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) while `quicklistp.org` from your working example does not need SNI.

If I interpret your code correctly you first create a TCP connection to the target host and then wrap TLS around this connection. Since you don't provide any information about the target hostname while doing this wrapping I will assume that the TLS wrapper will not be aware of the hostname and thus cannot tell the server the requested hostname inside the TLS handshake, i.e. it cannot use SNI. Since the server requires SNI the connection will fail.

According [to the documentation](https://common-lisp.net/project/cl-plus-ssl/) there is a way to specify the hostname. From the documentation:

```
Function CL+SSL:MAKE-SSL-CLIENT-STREAM 
(fd-or-stream &key 
   external-format certificate key password close-callback 
   (unwrap-streams-p t) 
   hostname
 )
 ...
 hostname if specified, will be sent by client during TLS negotiation, 
 according to the Server Name Indication (SNI) extension to the TLS.
```

Apart from that:
 you are doing a `HTTP/1.1` request but don't have the ability to handle `HTTP/1.1` responses like chunked encoding properly. For simply requests like yours I would recommend to use `HTTP/1.0` only. Also your code expects the server to close the connection after the data transfer is done, i.e. you don't extract body size from HTTP header and read only the given number of bytes. Using `Connection: keep-alive` in this situation is a bad idea because this way you ask the server to keep the connection open after the body is sent. Also `Connection: keep-alive` is implicit when using `HTTP/1.1` anyway.

Comment: Hi, Steffen  Thank you for your great explanation.  I modify the code with the hostname added, then it works.

Answer (score 0):

According to Steffen's great explanation, I figure out the way to make it work:

```
(usocket:with-client-socket (sock stream "beta.quicklisp.org" 443)
  (let ((https (cl+ssl:make-ssl-client-stream
                stream :unwrap-stream-p t
                :external-format '(:iso-8859-1 :eol-style :lf)
                :hostname "beta.quicklisp.org")))
    (unwind-protect
         (progn
           (format https "GET /quicklisp.lisp HTTP/1.0~%Host:beta.quicklisp.org~%Accept: */*~2%")
           (force-output https)
           (loop for line = (read-line https nil)
              while line do (format t "HTTPS> ~a~%" line)))
      (close https))))
```

Thanks, Steffen.